# Android "Hello World" Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu

I'm new to Android development. I'm running Eclipse with the ADT plugin and installed all the necessary dependencies. I open up Eclipse, select 'New Android Applciation' and everything is set. When I run the app, I get an error message saying

```
/home/parallels/workspace/test/AndroidManifest.xml: 2: /home/parallels/workspace/test/AndroidManifest.xml: Syntax error: newline unexpected
```

So I look in Android Manifest and it's just the default, Eclipse generated code, right? What's the problem here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Older versions of the ADT plugin had the problem, for me, of getting the wrong newline terminator in XML files. The only way I could fix the problem was to open the file (in Eclipse), delete the newline, and press enter. I don't know what the "wrong" newline terminator is in this instance, but pressing enter myself was how I fixed it.

Comment: Hmmm. This is EXACTLY what I get line for line when generating a new project. It works with me, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows?

Comment: I'm not sure that cleaning will help in this situation but worth a try. "Project --> Clean..."

Answer (score 0):

Is there any empty space above your first line in your manifest? That has to be at the very top. Also have you compiled anything successfully thus far? Maybe something didn't get imported properly. I recommend android studio. It's just Googles modified version of eclipse that specializes in android development. It comes with everything you need all ready to go.

Comment: The eclipse package they provide also comes with everything, also, Android Studio is still in beta stages.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend AS, especially to a beginner. It is still new and has many bugs.

Comment: Both are true. But android studio is much easier to program with. Even with the few bugs.